# Code snippet "cw" is gone

Tags: c#

Suddenly I found, that code snippet I used in past not work anymore in my `VS2017 C#`.

I write `cw` and press `tab` two times. I was expecting `Console.WriteLine();` to be written, but got `chat` after first `tab` pressed.

How to brink back `cw` code snippet?

Comment: Tools > Code Snippet Manager and import it if it is available, if not, create your own snippet and import that one. It should be located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\cw.snippet`

Comment: @Vico cw is a famous Resharper default snippet. I guess you didn't install resharper on your VS2017

Comment: I dont't have Resharper installed on my system, but I still have cw Code Snippet Manager. Does it comes with Resharper or standart VS installtion?

Why I can't enable or add cw in Code Snippet Manager?  https://i.imgur.com/4cYf5bX.png

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in a file named **cw.snippet** and place it in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>cw</Title>
            <Shortcut>cw</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for Console.WriteLine</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$SystemConsole$.WriteLine($end$);]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```